# React: Is there a way to capture changes to props sent via history.push

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing a component that uploads parameters to the server in promises. While the parameters are uploading I redirect to another component and send the parameters object as props, like this:

```
this.props.history.push('/new-page/createForm', {
    parameters: this.state.parameters

});
```

At the create Form component, I'm receiving the props and rendering the state of the upload of the parameters, and they render as uploading (because they haven't finished uploading).

Back to the previous component, once the parameters upload promise finishes, I update the parameters object to reflect the new state, i.e, uploaded.

```
ParamsService.uploadParam(parameter, uploadRoot)
.then(() => {
parameter.status = 'Uploaded';
})
```

Now, once the parameters are uploaded, I want the create form to automatically re-render in order to reflect the new state of the parameters, but this is not happening automatically.

However, if I perform an action in the form, such as filling one of the input fields, which trigger a React rendering, the parameters show as uploaded.

Is there a way to recognize the props change in the new create form and re-render once the parameters state change to uploaded?

I've tried componentDidUpdate and getDerivedStateFromProps but such functions do not trigger when the parameters status change to uploaded.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

see if [react-url-query](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-url-query)  solve your problems.

as the example in readme, once you use the HOC like

```
export default addUrlProps({
  urlPropsQueryConfig: {
    foo: { type: UrlQueryParamTypes.number, queryParam: 'fooInUrl' }
  },
})(MyComponent);
```

MyComponent will receive 2 props `this.props.foo` and `this.props.onChangeFoo` which allow you to get the value and allow you to change the url params `?fooInUrl`

Solution for React hooks: [use-query-params](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-query-params)